# How can I migrate my openings from Chess Position Trainer to another database when the pgn too large to import?

Tags: software, pgn

I have used [Chess Position Trainer](https://www.chesspositiontrainer.com) for years.  I now only play "postal" chess and no longer memorize openings.  Also chess position trainer is the only application I have the requires windows and I would like to stop using windows.

Some of my openings seem to be too large to import.  I have tried importing into chess tempo, ChessBase, and a local HIARCS chess explorer and they all error on import for large openings.

Chess Position Trainer supports exporting as a single PGN or a game per variation.  exporting as a game per variation scales better but still does not work for my largest openings such as King's Indian as black.

How can I migrate my openings from Chess Position Trainer to another database?

I am using Chess Position Trainer 5.04

My preference was to use Chess Tempo but would be happy for suggestions of other chess database software to try, either browser based or local for my mac.

Comment: What version of CPT are you currently using? What is your preference as to where to move them? It sounds less like a CPT question than a where you trying to move the data question, and that limitation.

Comment: Also, when exporting from CPT, have you tried the "“One  Game  per  Variation” export option to keep the number of lines per game down?

Comment: @PhishMaster I edited question to include version number and a preferred destination.  Using "One Game per Variation" helps but some openings are still too large, for example Kings Indian as Black.

Comment: I had been looking at that while waiting for a response, and it does seem like a limitation of the receiving sites, and thus, you will need to edit your output. In other words, manually break down any PGN files that are too big into smaller files. I am not an expert in things like Python, but perhaps there is a way for it to break down those automatically (this would be ripe for another question). You might want to message Chess Tempo and ask them what the maximum file size, or position depth, that their site can import.

Comment: The fact that it allows you to export your database as a single PGN makes it promising, because with the PGN we can easily reformat it according to requirements of the software you'll be using next. Please clarify where you want to be importing the database, how should it be structured, and it also helps if you provided a working example (such as a small PGN file with which you can elucidate the problem).

Comment: @Phonon The problem seems to be purely one of size so a small file will not demonstrate the problem.  With chess tempo I find I am able to import a 5MB pgn but not a 50MB pgn.  My browser just hangs.  I am happy to use some other database software that doesn't require windows.  Tomorrow I will try to split my 100MB pgn into 5MB chunks and see if I can import those into a single opening in chess tempo.

Comment: @MichaelWest You just added in a comment: " My browser just hangs." Have you tried a different browser? If you used Firefox, try Chrome, of vice versa.

Comment: By using a smaller file I got a good error message from chess tempo.  I am hitting the limit of number of positions allowed for my membership level.  Info on that here https://www.chesstempo.com/memberships/  For the highest level membership 60k positions are allowed.  I have more positions than that so chess tempo is not a good option for me.  So now I have a different question about chess database for a mac.  This has been asked and answered before, for example https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/690/alternatives-to-chessbase-on-os-x  I'll try some of those options.

Answer (score 1):

You can export subsets of your tree of moves or export each variation as an individual game within the same file. Acording to the [manual](https://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/download/manuals/CPT5_1_manual.pdf): "You can export an opening or topic as PGN file which then can be imported by many other chess programs. Several options let you configure the export to your preferences. The  most importantone might be the option to export as “One Game” or “One  Game  per  Variation” (the latter is only available for openings).